# Don't kill remote script when local caller process gets killed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, nohup

## Problem

I call a long running process via ssh. And it's necessary that this process will not be killed. The user may kill the initial process on its host and I cannot do anything about it.

How to make the remote process not be killed if the initial process gets killed?

`User -> user.sh -> SSH-to-remote -> long-running.sh`

It must:

1. Output the output of the remoteprocess
2. Exit when the remote process exits
3. Don't kill the remote process, wenn the initial process gets killed
4. Make an output log file available

## First incomplete solution

I thought about something using nohup but it didn't work so far:

`User -> user.sh -> SSH-to-remote -> init.sh -> long-running.sh`

init.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./long-running.sh >out.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
pid=$!
disown $pid
tail -f out.log &
wait $pid
```

long-running.sh (content for testing)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 30)
do 
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
```

This solution doesn't solve 2. It doesn't exit when the remote process exits.

Comment: Im using either [tmux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) or systemctl. The latter needs a small servicefile [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1336578/906933) to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution.

init.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./long-running.sh >out.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
pid=$!
disown $pid
tail --pid=$pid -f out.log
```

In my first solution `wait` didn't wait as `disown` removed the jobspec. `tail` ran forever and kept the session open.

Now `wait` was removed and `tail` waits for the process to exit. A kill from the source host kills tail but doesn't kills the long-running process.